# How to keep imports at top of file while loading env vars in imported libraries?

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, pep8, google-cloud-kms

Here is a very simple cloud function:

lib.py

```
import os
TOKEN = os.environ['TOKEN']

some_func(token=TOKEN):
    return token
```

main.py - runs when function invoked and main() is entrypoint.

```
import os
from lib import some_func

# This is a simplification of KMS secret injection
def inject_secrets():
    os.environ['TOKEN'] = 'SOMETOKEN'

inject_secrets()

def main():
   ...
```

On deploy, this causes the error:
`ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) OperationError: code=3, message=Function failed on loading user code. Error message: 'TOKEN'`

The failure happens because `TOKEN = os.environ['TOKEN']` is called when `some_func` is imported from `lib`.

One solution is to move when the import happens like so:

```
import os

def inject_secrets():
    os.environ['TOKEN'] = 'SOMETOKEN'

inject_secrets()
# Import moved after secret injection
from lib import some_func
```

This deploys and works but does not follow PEP8 because all imports should be at the top of the file.

What is a better solution to this problem?

Comment: I think you want to move the default value into the function body: `some_func(token=None): token = TOKEN if token is None`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [environment variables](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/env-var) in your `gcloud functions deploy` command, e.g.:

```
gcloud functions deploy FUNCTION_NAME --set-env-vars TOKEN=SOMETOKEN FLAGS...
```